# Is Erich Fromm's claim that the extended use of "have" corresponds to the rise of the market economy and Protestantism accurate?

Tags: historical-change

In the book [To Have or to Be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Have_or_to_Be%3F) Erich Fromm claims using "have" in English increased due to the rise of the market economy and Protestantism. Where one is alone in the market, with their personal relationship to God, rather than being part of a feudal economy and church where they are taken care of. How well is another conversation, but the point is they didn't talk in terms of how much they personally have so much, unlike in the market economy, where what they have is all they can depend on, with the rise of private property. He wrote that this is the cause of "have" being used in more cases such as "I want to have a party", instead of "I want to make a party", as one may see in other languages. England was ahead of others in the assimilation of a market economy (besides the Dutch). I'm not sure how English compared to others concerning amendability to change though. I did not see similar explanations in the etymology of "have". So the question is, how accurate is his explanation?

This question can be answered with examples of people changed lifestyles of people along with changes in language. Things happen for reasons, the answer would give the reason, whether agreeing with the question or not.

Comment: What timeframe is he suggesting this took place over?

Comment: Maybe centuries, at least decades, I'm not sure.

Comment: English seems to have been one of the more flexible languages -- consider the way it incorporated lots of French vocabulary when the Normans invaded.

Comment: Yeah english doesn't have something like the french academy that enforces language rules, I don't think.

Comment: He does provide some examples. I don't have the book.

Comment: I don't see how this question is intrinsically opinion-based. That people disagree with the premise, or that answers might consist of opinions, has nothing to do with the question's validity.

Comment: Yes it seems a valid question, although maybe a bit too large to answer here. But maybe there have been other people commenting or critiquing on it that we can reference without doing a full historical analysis.

Comment: This was the man's opinion. Nothing else. After all, his book is called To Have or to Be.  This is not about etymology. It's just his take on all this. https://daily-philosophy.com/to-have-or-to-be/

Comment: If the usage of 'have' did expand, there would be reasons for it. Reasons are not opinions, people support their explanations with evidence. If people say history is open to interpretation, and thus makes it off topic, since all history is opinion since we don't have time machines, seems a little odd. Like we can't talk about history then? Why the historical change tag?

Comment: How is OP going to accept an answer if they're gone already?